# Error 1064 MySql Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have this following code to create an Order table in my database:

```
create table order(
order_id int primary key not null auto_increment,
product_id int not null,
customer_id int not null,
date_created datetime not null default now(),
date_modified datetime not null default now(),
order_status varchar(25),
foreign key(product_id) references product(product_id),
foreign key(customer_id) references customer(customer_id));
```

but when I execute it I get this error:

> You have an error in you SQL syntax:check the manual that corresponds
>   to your Mysql server version for the right syntaxt to use
>   near'order(order_id int primary key not null auto_increment,product_id
>   int not null,c'

Please help e figure out what's the issue.

Comment: Wrap the `order` with back ticks : `

Comment: Primary key is implicitly not null, try removing the not null constraint.